# How to transfer ether from one account to another using EthereumJ

Tags: ethereumj

For testing purpose in test network we are creating account dynamically using ethereum java (EcKey). I have an account that contains enough ethers. How can i transfer ether from the source account to the account newly created using ethereum java. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Check any sample from [samples source directory](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/tree/develop/ethereumj-core/src/main/java/org/ethereum/samples) how to deal with Transactions, for example, this one: [CreateContractSample.java](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/blob/develop/ethereumj-core/src/main/java/org/ethereum/samples/CreateContractSample.java#L82-L96),

Your transaction call should be something like this:

```
// Amount in ether to send
BigInteger etherToSend = BigInteger.valueOf(100);
// Weis in 1 ether
BigInteger weisInEther = BigInteger.valueOf(1_000_000_000_000_000_000L);
BigInteger weisToSend = weisInEther.multiply(etherToSend);
BigInteger nonce = ethereum.getRepository().getNonce(senderKey.getAddress());

Transaction tx = new Transaction(
      ByteUtil.bigIntegerToBytes(nonce),
      ByteUtil.longToBytesNoLeadZeroes(ethereum.getGasPrice()),
      ByteUtil.longToBytesNoLeadZeroes(3_000_000),  // Gas limit
      receiveAddress,
      ByteUtil.bigIntegerToBytes(weisToSend),  // Amount in weis
      new byte[0]  // We don't need to send any data
     ); 
tx.sign(senderKey);
ethereum.submitTransaction(tx);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Transaction.java class , create the object with information needed ( the constructor, takes info like from, to address,nonce,gas and value to transfer) and
finally sign the transaction and submit.