# How to sign transaction for calling sendRawTransaction JSON RPC method?

Tags: json-rpc, testnets, java

I have a private ethereum network and a java process with communicates with a ethereum node with JSON RPC.

I need to add a transaction from java process by calling the `sendRawTransaction` RPC method.

How can I sign the transaction to be passed to a `sendRawTransaction` call?

Comment: Do you mean how do you sign it? You shouldn't need to encrypt it.

Comment: @EdmundEdgar, yes, I meant signing, not encrypting. I updated the question.

Comment: Though not Java, jou might find this helpful as it contains the example for JavaScript: https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ethereum-smart-contract-transaction-demo/blob/master/src/txbuilder.js#L69 - tutorial blog post https://tokenmarket.net/blog/creating-ethereum-smart-contract-transactions-in-client-side-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

You might find this answer helpful: [How to transfer ether from one account to another using EthereumJ](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6777/how-to-transfer-ether-from-one-account-to-another-using-ethereumj)

It gives an example of using the EthereumJ java library to create a transaction and sign it with a private key. It uses the `Transaction sign()` method. The example goes on to submit the transaction via the library, but for your case you could serialize it and submit it to the `sendRawTransaction` RPC call.

Something like:

```
Transaction tx = new Transaction( ... );
tx.sign(senderKey);
String hex =  Hex.toHexString(tx.getEncoded())
```

See the example  here: https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/blob/develop/ethereumj-core/src/main/java/org/ethereum/samples/SendTransaction.java